# Can I use a wireless access point (or two) to extend my existing wireless network?

Tags: router, wireless, network, access-point

In large commercial buildings I typically see several ceiling mounted Wireless Access Points.  When moving throughout the building, I do not have to continually reconnect to different networks (or SSIDs).

I assumed this is what WAPs do: You plug them into your Router or Switch and they create a wireless network.  You would then give the same SSID from your existing wireless network and you would have a larger, better network.

However, posts such as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/122441/how-can-i-get-the-same-ssid-for-multiple-access-points) make it seem like each WAP may need to have its own SSID.

If this is the case - how do large commercial businesses create large, non-mesh wifi networks?

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic, except on [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se]. As far a business go, there are a few ways to do this, and you would need to ask the specific business. Questions about networks not under your direct control are off-topic here.

Comment: @RonMaupin I deleted the product request - but this question is very similar to the linked-to (non-closed topic :)

Comment: Your assumption is correct.  In non-mesh wireless networks, you can still configure all of the APs to broadcast the same SSIDs so you can move between them nearly seamlessly. The difference between mesh and non-mesh is essentially just how the connections get back to the main gateway/router.  Non-mesh has to have a direct path to the main gateway; mesh can do that or talk to each other to get a path back.

Comment: Most large non-mesh networks are still controlled through wireless controllers which also allow for things such as fast (or rapid) transitioning, so clients can move between APs without having a drop, by the client establishing a connection to the second (stronger) AP before terminating the connection to the first (weaker) AP.

Comment: @JesseP but the "wire controller" part is optional essentially?

Comment: @Startec Most of the time, yes. But it depends on what you want to do on your wireless network.  If you want a guest SSID with a EULA, you usually need a controller to do that, for example. Using a controller makes it easier to manage large amounts of APs too. If you have less than a dozen, I usually go without a controller and manage the APs directly.  It's partially up to preference.

Comment: I just want to increase the strength in one room in my house and only have one SSID.

Comment: @Startec Home/consumer networking is off limits here.  You can ask on [su] if you want.  You originally made it appear as though you were needing help with commercial buildings but now that you've said it's for your house, we can't help here.